# What does the colon signify in a C function?

Tags: c, syntax

What is this use of the colon called?

The following code is taken from the book *Learn Core Audio*.

```
    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
    //...

    cleanup:
        AudioQueueDispose(queue, true);
        AudioFileClose(player.playbackFile);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There are a few other contexts where a colon can appear.  `i = (j > k) ? l : m;` (ternary or conditional operator); `case 'A':` and `default:` (labels in a `switch` statement), and defining bit-fields: `struct x { unsigned int x : 2; } a;`.  I think that list completes the syntactic uses of colon in C.  C++ has more uses for it: it uses `::` for scoping and `:` in range-based loops, etc.

Comment: I knew about the ternary operator. It was just odd that nothing came up about labels. I guess "c function colon use" is too vague of a thing to Google. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a label. It's used along with a `goto` statement to control the flow of your program.

[goto and Labeled Statements (C)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c002fdz.aspx)

Comment: For the record, you should be careful around goto statements: [they can lead to velociraptors](http://xkcd.com/292/).

Answer (score 3):

`cleanup:` is a label. It can be used as the target for a `goto` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Cleanup is a label. You can use

```
goto cleanup;
```

In your code to redirect your execution from cleanup label.